# Shell script to validate mount point status in the linux server

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm in need of a script which should work as below.

A script where it would validate if that specific mountpoint is currently mounted on the server. It would search for mountpoint name in `/etc/fstab` and then validate either from `df -h` output or `/proc/mounts` to check if its mounted on the server (if you have any better way to validate thats also fine).

After reboot, in case it does not gets mounted  it would trigger an email.

For one server its okay but this is going to be used to validate more than 1000 servers so a script would be better solution.

So the script would be executed on one server and it would check for mountpoint status in another 1000 server.

Mountpoint in the server is in the name of `/mount1`, `/mount2`, `/mount3` etc.
We need to validate this specific mountpoint name only, we can ignore other OS related FS.

What I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Grep for word mountpoint name ie "mount" 
awk '{print $2}' /etc/fstab | grep -i "mount" > mntpoint.txt
exec 3< mntpoint.txt

while read mount <&3
do
# Search for present mountpoint in file /prod/mounts.
# I'm using /proc/mounts here to validate

grep -iw $mount /proc/mounts > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo $mount "is mounted"
else
    echo $mount "is not mounted needs manual intervention"
fi
done
```

Comment: What have you already tried? In general, we don't just write out huge systems on demand, but help you in writing one when you get stuck doing so.

Comment: Hi, this is not a "We write your code for free!" webpage. Perhaps you were looking for http://www.rent-acoder.com/? Please attempt to write the script yourself and post here if you have a _specific_ problem we can help you with. Have a look at our [help] pages for information on what kinds of questions one can ask here.

Comment: Sure Chris,I understand...This is what I am trying in one of the server.
It would let me know which mountpoint is currently missing.
But same script has to be executed from one server and it should login to each server and provide output.
So is it that it has to be copied to destination server, run it there and send the output back to original server ?

Comment: The script which I am trying to copy above doesnot follow indentation !! sorry about it ..is there better way to put my script in this post

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying this in python.  The built-in os.path module has a very simple ismount feature.

```
$ cat ismount.py 
import os
mp = '/mount1'
if os.path.ismount(mp):
    print('{0} is mounted'.format(mp))
else:
    print('{0} is NOT mounted'.format(mp))
$ python ismount.py 
/mount1 is NOT mounted
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. First create a list of server IPs (this assumes that you have password-less ssh set up and can connect as root to all severs) then, run this little script (copy paste into the command line):

```
while read ip;
do
    echo "connecting to $ip";
    ssh root@$ip "until mount | grep -w \"$MOUNT\" >/dev/null;
     do echo mounting \"$MOUNT\"; mount \"$MOUNT\"; sleep 1; done && 
     echo Mounted on $ip"
done < ips.txt
```

This expects a file called `ips.txt` with one IP per line. It will `ssh` into the IP, and while the mount `$MOUNT` is not mounted, it will attempt to do so.
Make sure to replace `$MOUNT` with the mount point you are interested in, **it should appear exactly as it does in `/etc/fstab`**. For example:

```
while read ip;
do
    echo "connecting to $ip";
    ssh root@$ip "until mount | grep -w \"/mnt/data\" >/dev/null;
     do echo mounting \"/mnt/data\"; mount \"/mnt/data\"; sleep 1; done && 
     echo Mounted on $ip"
done < ips.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

A=``awk '{print $2}' /etc/fstab | grep -i "^/" | egrep -v '/etc/fstab|proc|sys|shm|pts`'`

`for i in $A; do
grep $i /proc/mounts > /dev/null`

`if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $i "is mounted"
else
    echo $i "is not mounted needs manual intervention"
fi
done`
```

Comment: This will return false positives if the path is a substring of a larger mountpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The script provided by LG works fine when you change the grep in the for-loop to:

```
grep "$i " /proc/mounts.
```

In that case it won't return false positives.